# What does "command1 -> command2" indicate in results from my ls -al?

Tags: solaris, ls

when I do a `ls -al` in `/usr/sfw/bin` I see: `make -> gmake` What does this indicate? Is this a symbolic link? I've googled and have not found the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a symbolic link. You can try something like below.

```
bash-3.2$ mkdir a
bash-3.2$ ln -s a b
bash-3.2$ ls -al b
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ramesh ramesh 1 May 28 19:10 b -> a
```

`b` is a symbolic link pointing to `a`.

**Difference between a symbolic link and hard link**

A file in the file system is basically a link to an inode.
A hard link then just creates another file with a link to the same underlying inode.

When you delete a file it removes one link to the underlying inode. The inode is only deleted (or deletable/over-writable) when all links to the inode have been deleted.

A symbolic link is a link to another name in the file system.

Once a hard link has been made the link is to the inode. deleting renaming or moving the original file will not affect the hard link as it links to the underlying inode. Any changes to the data on the inode is reflected in all files that refer to that inode.

Note: Hard links are only valid within the same File System. Symbolic links can span file systems as they are simply the name of another file.

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible for me to create a symbolic link only used by myself?

Comment: @DemiSheep, see the updated answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but, from what I've read, if I create a symbolic link for my user it'll be for all users of the system, is that correct? So if I want to create one for myself only I would need to add it to my .profile or .bashrc file -- though I don't see how I would remove it when I log out unless there is some sort of logout script I don't know about.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a symbolic link. You can use the -L option with ls to see the attributes of the actual underlying thing being pointed to, rather than the attributes of the symlink itself (owner/group/mode of a symlink is rather uninteresting, you usually care about the thing being pointed to).

Comment: Can you give an example? I am trying to do this but it doesn't seem to work on my Solaris system in my bash shell.

Comment: Sure. Wish I could do a code block in a comment. Follow Ramesh's complete example to create a symlink. Now add a file into the directory a by doing "touch a/foofile". Now type "ls -lL b", and you should see foofile. Try it with and without the L option. If you do "ls -ldL b", you'll see the owner/group/mode of the directory a itself. Try chmod to alter mode of a, and do the ls again. Hope that helps clarify. By the way, I used Solaris for 25 years, I guarantee it works the same way :)

Comment: By the way, when I suggested using chmod to alter the mode of directory 'a', maybe just try turning on/off the write permission e.g. 'chmod o-w a' or 'chmod o+w a'. Potentially surprising things will happen if you play with read/execute perms on directories and that's another subject entirely.

Comment: @DemiSheep: Did this work for you?

Comment: I tried testing out the -L thing on the existing symlink I had and I don't think it worked the same way - I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is link notation as other's have described. I'll just add that whenever you encounter files in your filesystem that you're unsure what they are you can use the `file` command to determine their type.

#### Examples

```
$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 saml saml 4096 May 28 19:47 dir1
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 saml saml 4096 May 28 19:52 dir2
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 saml saml    0 May 28 19:41 file1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 saml saml    5 May 28 20:55 link -> file1
```

*link*

```
$ file link 
link: symbolic link to `file1'
```

*file*

```
$ file file1 
file1: empty
```

*directory*

```
$ file dir1
dir1: directory
```

The output of `ls -l` also reflects the types with the first column.

- `d` = directory
- `l` = link
- `-` = a file

**NOTE:** There are other types that can be shown here. Things such as fifos, and character devices, among others.

#### References

- [Unix File Types - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types)